# AS3/Flash - SoundCloud Streaming (crossdomain.xml)

Tags: flash, audio, soundcloud

Is it possible to stream an audio file through flash without embedding the sc player? What i mean is accessing the audio file without any redirects plus granting access through crossdomain.xml.

SoundCloud closed access into sound, in Flash.

Can  anyone help what to do?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Do you need to use flash, or could you use something like Javascript?

Comment: Finally I did it with JS.